# Can I use Araldite to stick PLA to metal frame?

Tags: pla, post-processing

I have a PLA base, that the MOSFETs are sitting on. I don't want to drill through the base of the printer, I was thinking of using Araldite to stick the PLA base to the metal frame. The PLA base will be stuck to the base of the 3D printer upside down.

Do you think this will work long term? I don't want the plastic falling off and the MOSFETs hitting the metal base.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! Why not use superglue? It will hold to both surfaces without issue.

Comment: I tried it seems to stick ok. hope it lasts for a long time. since my printer is now working i will just print a plastic guard.

Comment: [This is the reason I suggested superglue.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6723/11242)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I guess that the base of the MOSFETs are not flat (component pins); Araldite is an epoxy which has better filling properties.

Comment: @0scar Araldite can be epoxy or PU or Cyanoacrylic

Comment: @Trish Thanks! I only know it as epoxy, which appears the best adhesive for this application.

Answer (score 3):

[Araldite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araldite) is a brand that refers to a range of structural epoxy, acrylic and polyurethane adhesives. Among the [vast number of products](http://www.go-araldite.com) marketed under the name are also "metal repair" paste and what seems to be silicone based glues. Depending on what Araldite you have on hand, all of these types can be useful for PLA and any other 3D-printing material, as I had elaborated [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6725/8884). I suggest grabbing either an epoxy or PU variant or some kind of silicone for this use. You should make sure several things though if you go with epoxy or PU:

- make a small sample print and clamp down one side, then put a small weight on the other side. Apply the glue in the center of it. If it sags considerably during the bonding, the heat of the glue curing is warm enough to soften the print. If this happens, you should take precautions to prevent it from deforming during the bonding, e.g. not apply too much pressure onto the bond.
- The MOSFET can get rather hot. Make sure that the clamp holding the MOSFET still holds the item as it gets hot, as PLA starts to get malleable enough to deform under stress at 50 °C and usually fails quickly at about 100 °C.

Silicone-based glues depend on an area to force ratio to stick but offer a flexible bond that is somewhat thermal resistant and very gap filling.