# What glues to use for PETG?

Tags: post-processing, petg, glue

In analogy to: [What glues for bonding printed PLA to injection-molded plastic?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6723/4762), what are the best glues to use for PETG?

I mostly print in PETG and have occasional failed prints which I usually reprint. But what if I'd like to repair a print e.g. a split between layers or a part broken off?

Knowing that PETG is more "greasy" than PLA, what typical glues can you use to create a good bond; this question excludes using heat to (re-)bond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  [forum](https://forum.simplify3d.com/viewtopic.php?t=9281)

> Bison plastic - works great for me, only it's not "quick dry" but it's very strong, not brittle, holds PETG and PLA very strongly. 
>   Buy paint stripper that is/contains methylene chloride (dichloromethane). It will solvent weld both PLA and PETG.

Or see  [other forum](https://all3dp.com/2/best-glue-for-plastic-pla-abs-petg-nylon/)  which recommends Eastman-910 (original brand of cyanoacrylate) or any equivalent, polyurethane glue, or even epoxy.

Answer (score 2):

A strong epoxy like BSI 5-15 min works great for me. I use it to bond high power rocket fin halves printed from PETG:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If Carl's answer that cyanoacrylate glue works is accurate, I would suggest Loctite 420 or equivalent. It's diluted with solvents sufficiently to behave as a liquid rather than a gel, and in my experience on PLA it not only bonds the joint, but wicks between the extrusions and bonds walls/layers together much more strongly and waterproofs the part. As long as it bonds to PETG it should do the same for PETG.