# How to get superglue off PLA filament?

Tags: pla, post-processing

So I'm making my friend a Monado sword replica and I've printed the handle in 2 pieces as to fill it with electronics and then superglue the 2 halves together.

I seem to have put too much on and it's leaked out and spread as shown in the picture..

Does anyone know how to get the dried glue off?
[image]

Thanks,

(PS. The glue is called "NO NONSENSE SUPERGLUE")

Comment: Relevant Reverse: [What Glues For PLA](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6723/what-glues-for-pla)

Answer (score 5):

In agreement with what Akriss said, pretty much all "super" glue is CA (cyanoacrylate) glue, which is soluble in acetone. PLA itself is does not dissolve in or react with acetone, but the pigments, additives, etc. likely do, so you should wipe with a paper towel or cloth (the latter might be better to avoid getting fibers stuck on the glue) soaked in acetone rather than pouring it over the piece or submerging it, to limit the effects. Also, test first on a scrap piece printed with the same filament to ensure the results aren't unacceptably bad.

Comment: The caution of not soaking is it could unglue your parts.  A good idea is to combine polishing after lightly painting with acetone.  Use eye protection and good ventilation.

Comment: @PerryWebb: Indeed that's also a consideration, but the issue I described applies even if the glue was just dripped on a PLA part that wasn't broken and didn't need glue.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Acetone before. However that said I've not had the need to remove it from PLA. Not sure how PLA reacts to Acetone.

A link that may be of use.
https://www.art-us.com/how-to-get-super-glue-off-almost-anything/

Answer (score 0):

Acetone hasn't worked at all for me, if anything it made it worse by stripping the PLA of the sheen its supposed to have. I have tried various types of Acetone as well, all with similar results.

I know this will sound crazy, but I have been doing this for about 6 months. I use Sesame Oil, applied generously with a Q-tip, and then I "rub it in/dry it off" with a paper towel. This has worked on various sheens of PLA and PLA+ and completely removes any evidence of super glue. I haven't seen the oil dry out yet either. At first I thought the oil would wear off or dry out, but it has not yet and its been 6 months since I've been doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try wiping with Vaseline petroleum jelly. It effectively removes the white haze that sometimes forms around a joint glued with cyanoacrylate. It may remove or diminish the color of the glue residue, though will not remove the glue itself.