# Large prints cracking

Tags: print-quality, polycarbonate

I'm trying to print large objects (around 1 meter squared) with polycarbonate pellets. The problem is sometimes the print cracks. It is not due to delamination as it is a shear crack across multiple layers. I know the ideal scenario is to have a heated enclosure but I cannot do that due to the size. Any suggestions?

I am using a robotic arm (KUKA KR360) with a custom extruder. That is why I can't build the enclosure. As for the temperature, they are 230 to 260 °C. Nozzle is 10 mm.

---

*I like the idea of directed heat. I might try that.*

Comment: You need to tell us what printer you are using, nozzle size and temps.

Answer (score 1):

Printing polycarbonate requires a high end 3D printer that is suitable for the task.

From [Simplify3d support](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/materials-guide/polycarbonate/) we learn that:

> ... requires very high temperatures for printing and will **exhibit layer separation if printed at too low of a temperature or with excessive cooling enabled**. Polycarbonate is frequently **best printed on a machine that has an enclosed build volume** and is capable of handling high bed and extruder temperatures.

High temperatures and enclosed build volume are key to print polycarbonate without cracking or delamination.

> Any suggestions?

Note that NASA has successfully printed ULTEM (even higher temperatures needed) [using open source hardware](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20170000214). They have used infrared lamps directed at the build plate, this may be an option if a full enclosure is not possible. Also people seem to get good results with draft shields for printing ABS on non enclosed printers. Key is that a constant elevated temperature is created near the print, whether that works for such a large size remains to be seen. Best solution would be enclosing the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your problem is cooling, which would be mitigated by an enclosure to eliminate draughts and hold a higher air temperature.

I made an enclosure using parts-on-hand and some printed PLA joiners.  It doesn't have to be fancy or expensive to work well.

Details are at https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/18406/12956

Next step is to sew some thermal "curtains" as sides and top.  As it is I simply hang some coats around the frame in the short term, and use a Pi camera inside to monitor the progress from remote.

Answer (score -1):

Get a tent for growing smokey plants :)
Think about it, they can be of big sizes and maintain heat inside, reflective material on the inside.

Comment: The idea of using an enclosure has already been mentioned in the other answer provided. Please [edit] your answer to provide additional details with supporting documentation/links.